# Get selected option value from specific select

Tags: jquery, html

I can not get the selected `<option>` value. `<select>`s are formed dynamically from database into table rows. All `<select>`s have same class name.

Here is my HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="std_code">2014-1-10</td>
    <td>Student 10</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>66</td>
    <td>
        <select class="degree_accept_id">
            <option value="1">BA(LAW)</option>
            <option value="2">BE(EE)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>17 November 2014</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="ee_accept_suggestion"><i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i></a>
    </td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="std_code">2014-1-9</td>
    <td>Student 9</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>69</td>
    <td>
        <select class="degree_accept_id">
            <option value="1">BA(LAW)</option>
            <option value="2">BE(EE)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>17 November 2014</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="ee_accept_suggestion"><i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i></a>
    </td>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="std_code">2014-1-8</td>
    <td>Student 8</td>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>71</td>
    <td>
        <select class="degree_accept_id">
            <option value="1">BA(LAW)</option>
            <option value="2">BE(EE)</option>
            <option value="3">BE(ME)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>17 November 2014</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="ee_accept_suggestion"><i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i></a>
    </td>  
</tr>
```

JS code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.ee_accept_suggestion').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var std_code = $(this).parent().siblings(".std_code").text();
            //var selected_degree = $(".degree_accept_id option:selected", this).attr("value");
            //var selected_degree = $(this).val();
            var selected_degree = $("select.degree_accept_id").val();
            alert(selected_degree);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem: `alert` always shows **1**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the selected value of the dropdown relative to the click event, use this

```
$('.ee_accept_suggestion').click(function(e){
 var dropdownValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.degree_accept_id').val();
```

What is happening is

- First, the clicked element is used `$(this)` and is wrapped in a jQuery object to have access to the API,
- .[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)`('tr')` searches itself first, and then for the first occurrence of parent nodes which are `<tr>`.
- Once the `<tr>` element is found, `.find('.degree_accept_id')` will locate the element under that `tr` classed as "degree_accept_id".
- jQuery's `.val()` gets the value associated with an input, select (in this case), or textarea element.

Comment: this actually works ! But what is the logic behind the $(this).closest('tr').find('.degree_accept_id').val();